# Rorke aurora raid 6 won’t load in linux

Tags: raid, restore

after a power failure a raid 6 won’t load in Linux without any disk failure
The message while booting is raid restored failed function: numaraid
Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there a command to restore the raid